# LeftAnti join in pyspark is too slow

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to do some operations on pyspark. Actually I have a big dataframe (90 Million Rows, 23 columns) and another dataframe (30k rows, 1 column).
I have to remove from the first dataframe all the occurrences where the value of a certain column matches any of the values of the second dataframe.

```
firstdf = firstdf.join(seconddf, on = ["Field"], how = "leftanti")
```

The problem is that this operation is extremely slow (about 13 mins on databricks). Is there any way to improve the performance of this operation?

Comment: that  isn't too slow, and the operation seems simple enough...

Comment: so it is the best option? making the second df a list and filtering with the isin couldn't improve performances?

Comment: try it and tell us :)

Comment: Unlikely solution: You could try in sql environment syntax: where fielid not in (select fieldid from df2) I doublt this is any faster tho.

Comment: I am currently translating sql commands into pyspark ones for sake of performances.. sql is a lot slower for our purposes so we are moving to dataframes.

Comment: @Marco Capusso did you benchmark the filter vs join? I guess the filter is a better fit but the number will tell. If you opt for the join, try broadcasting the smaller dataframe (https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/broadcast-joins/)